# How do I print out the result of a vector?

Tags: python, matrix, vector, multiplication

I am doing a few task about vector-matrix multiplication using Python. I think it is absolutely necessary to tell you that these tasks should be done without using NumPy.

```py
class Vec4():
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, w = 0):
        self.values = [x,y,z,w]
        ...

    def __str__(self):
        toReturn = ''
        if self is None: return '0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00'
        for c in range(0,4):
                toReturn += "%.2f" % self.values[c]
                if c != 3:
                    toReturn += ' '
        return toReturn

    def mul(self, v):
        x = ...
        y = ...
        z = ...
        w = ...
        return Vec4(x,y,z,w)
```

I don't post the complete code for some reasons. What I just want to know is how to use the print command here for the resulting vector.

```py
print(Vec4(x,y,z,w))
```

This print command doesn't work. What else can I do?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: 'doesn't work' is not a clear enough description of your problem. Do you expect something else to be printed? Then what would be your expected output? Hint: have a look at the `__str__` special method.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code. If I type in the solution from user10521398, it says that the code is unreachable. I want the resulting vector.

Comment: `print(Vec4(x,y,z,w).values)` would work. If you want it to be automatic, define a `__str__()` method that converts `self.values` into a string: i.e. `return str(self.values))`

Comment: You changed the question by including an `__str__` method that was originally empty, and still didn't explain how this code doesn't give your expected output. Also, please see how to create a [mcve].

Comment: This is the original code.

Comment: No, you changed it and you are still not explaining what's the prolem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.x) + ' ' + str(self.y) + ' ' + str(self.z) + ' ' + str(self.w)
```

When you will call for example `print(Vec4(1,2,3,4))` it should return `1 2 3 4`.

Comment: Thanks but the code block is different from yours.

Comment: I think that the only way to override the `print()` method is to redefine `__str__(self)`.

Comment: Anyway, is my output what you expect?

Comment: I can't say that because if I run the file, it just says unreachable code.

Comment: I mean, what is the output you want?

Comment: Something like "0.00 0.00 0.00 0.00".

Comment: So, why is my solution not good for you?

Comment: It works now with the Python IDLE. The result of the vector should be printed. You multiply two vectors with each other. The result should be printed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193194/discussion-between-user2379123-and-federico-domeniconi).